# Vue and php interaction

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vue-cli

Is it possible to pass variable from php script to javascript (twig for example, but it may be plain html with  of course) on first page loading?
I use **vue cli** and I can pass variable using ajax requests.
At my previous application with knockout.js i just wrote something like

```
<script>
    window.__initialServerData = {{ data|raw }};        
    console.log(__initialServerData);        
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you absolutely can render a value in a PHP variable into javascript. Here is an example:

```
<?php
    $variable = 'value';
?>

<script>
    var my_val = '<?=$variable?>';
    console.log(my_val);
</script>
```